# using linq to sql to specify where clause

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I am using this method to get results to fill my grid but this method is also used to fill another grid which requires a where clause with two params and this one
only needs one. Even though i passed in null of the param that isn't used but still it is returning no results because of the where clause. Any advice of how i could
change this maybe use linq to sql where i call the method to specify the where clause instead of in the method getting data?

```
DocsForReview.DataSource = docLib.GetGrid(Guid.Empty, lib); 

using (var dc = new DocMgmtDataContext())
{
    var subs = (from doc in dc.Documents
                join u in dc.Users on doc.OwnedByUserID equals u.ID
                where doc.OwnedByUserID == usr &&  doc.LibraryID == lib
                select new StudentDocuments
                {
                    DocID = doc.ID,
                    Assignment = doc.Library.Name,
                    Submitted = doc.UploadDT,
                     Student = u.FullName
                 }).OrderByDescending(c => c.Submitted).AsEnumerable().ToList();
    return subs;
}
```

Comment: wouldn't use Linq2Sql if this is a new project, use Linq2Entities

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For nullable types try this:

```
doc.LibraryID == (lib ?? doc.LibraryID)
```

In your case (a System.Guid) you can try this:

```
doc.LibraryID == (lib == Guid.Empty ? doc.LibraryID : lib)
```

Comment: because my lib and usr are guids i get the error `Operator ?? cannot be applied to operands of type system.guid`

Comment: learned something new. Thanks for your help - really appreciate it!